# PHP replace all occurences with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have a variable that contains a text, and i need to replace all occurrences that match a certain regular expression, each occurrence has to be changed by the result of a function that processes that occurrence's so i have to use `preg_replace_callback()` in order to pass each match to a callback that will then return the text to replace it. here is my code:

```
$fileContent = preg_replace_callback('/^.*video.*controls.*video.*$/m', function($matches){
                    foreach($matches as $k => $match){
                        $matches[$k] = str_replace('controls','controls controlsList=&quot;nodownload&quot;', $match);
                    }
                    return $matches;
                }, $fileContent);
```

This causes an error since the function must return a string, but i don't understand how it expects an array of matches as a parameter and return a string ?

Comment: When you insert a string you should return a string. This makes sense.

Comment: Btw, when you don't use round brackets, your matches will be empty.

Comment: @MarkusZeller but it takes an array of strings "matches" yet it returns a string ?

Comment: What is your expected result? Maybe you don't need a callback at all.

Comment: I need to replace all matches with a value related to the match value. Let's say i need to replace all matches (video followed by controls..) with it's uppercase for example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any capture groups, the match is in `$matches[0]`.

Use:

```
$fileContent = preg_replace_callback('/^.*video.*controls.*video.*$/m', function($matches){
                        $matches[0] = str_replace('controls','controls controlsList=&quot;nodownload&quot;', $match);
                    return $matches[0];
                }, $fileContent);
```

But, in your case, it is enough to do:

```
$fileContent = preg_replace('/^(.*video.*)controls(.*video.*)$/m', '$1controls controlsList=&quot;nodownload&quot;$2', $fileContent);
```

Comment: So when you don't have capture groups it will be an array with only 1 element ? what if there are multiple matches for the given pattern ?

Comment: @Badr: You may return a combination of all matches. But you replace 1 part of string at a time. callback is used when you want to transform the match before return. In fact, in your case you don't need callback, a simple `preg_replace` is enough.

Comment: I do transform the match before return, as you can see i replace 'controls' with 'controls controlsList...' in the match and return it.

Comment: preg_replace makes sense.